# Gstreamer rtsp to HLS, set EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME tag in m3u8 playlist file

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, http-live-streaming

I'm using Gstreamer to convert an rtsp stream to HLS. I want to set the EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME tag in the m3u8 playlist file. Is this possible? I'm using this terminal command but ideally I want to write a c program which does the same thing.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v -e rtspsrc protocols=tcp \
    location=rtsp://rtspadress \
    do-timestamp=true ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse config-interval=-1 ! mpegtsmux \
    ! hlssink location="%06d.ts" target-duration=5
```